# MySQL and PHP. My table doesnt exist

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp, dreamweaver

So i made a database in my phyMyAdmin and the time i encoded it with my html file and open it in chrome...it says that 
Table 'forum.form_tabl' doesn't exist
what happened and what should i do?
this is the code

```html
    <?php

session_start();
require"db_connect.php";
$sql= "SELECT forum_id,forum_name FROM form_tabl";

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <table>
  <?php if($query->num_rows !==0);
  while($row = $query->fetch()):
  ?>
  <tr><td><a href="forum.php"?id = <?php echo $forum_id?>"><?php echo $f_name;?></a>
   </td></tr>
   <?php endwhile;T_ENDIF;
  ?>
 </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>[enter image description here][1]
    //THE OTHER .PHP file is db_connect.php where i put the actual one

    <?php

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","forum") or die("ERROR! With Connection")
    ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVMsx.png)

Comment: Could you please tell me exact problem? because its seems that you are using prepare() and below again you are trying to establishing database connection by using mysqli

Comment: Check name of your table.And define your problem properly

Comment: @PramodKharade edited, thank you in advance

Comment: @MohitYadav when i open it in the browser it saysTable 'forum.form_tabl' doesn't exist

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\form.php on line 26

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\form.php on line 27

Comment: remove db_connect.php file and refer below code which will placed in ans.

Comment: where will i put the code? Thank you. Bigbig help. huge thanks sir @PramodKharade

Comment: @louie kim Please clear your basic concept.

Answer (score 1):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("HostName","UserName","password","DBName") or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));  

// Write query

$strSQL = "SELECT username FROM MyTable";

// Execute the query.

$query = mysqli_query($con, $strSQL);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $result["username"]."
";
}

// Close the connection
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```